# what this error and how to solve it with metamask wallet?

Tags: metamask, nft, ethereum-wallet-dapp, opensea

this error appears when the buyers buy nft item on opensea[image]

Internal JSON-RPC error. ( "code": -32016, "message": "The execution failed due to an exception.", "data"; "Reverted" )

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error with the smart contract.

Please post your code so that we can have a closer look, the error is not very explicit.

Comment: code for what? sir!

Comment: The code of the NFT contract that the buyer is interacting with.

Comment: I have no code, I just link my MetaMask wallet to the OpenSea, create a collection and upload my project then I listed it, If anything is missing please show me.

Comment: l will be glad if you help me.

Comment: How did you create a collection and upload your project ? Please contact the OpenSea support if you only used their tools.

Comment: what is smart contract

Comment: You should contact the Opensea support.